# How to find OAuth2 client registration id and use in Spring WebClient

Tags: oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webclient

I have a registered a client to access a web service using OAuth2. I know the client id, client secret and grant type and token endpoint. Does OAuth2 expose an endpoint to get the client registration id? If not, is there any other way to obtain the client registration id?

I am trying to use the client registration id to create a Spring Security ClientRegistration object for use in a Spring WebClient. Is there a way to create a OAuth2 enabled WebClient without the registration id?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any identifier of your choice as a `client registration id`. For example, you can name it after API your trying to access or Identity Provider name. It is used to get `ClientRegistration` from [ClientRegistrationRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/registration/ClientRegistrationRepository.html).

`ClientRegistrations` are loaded automatically from an `application.properties` file. Spring auto-configuration looks for properties with the schema `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.[registrationId]` and creates a `ClientRegistration` instance within a `ClientRegistrationRepository`.

You can refer to the following blog post for more examples of how to create and use `ClientRegistration` class: [Intro to Spring Security 5 Core Classes](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/05/05/client-credentials-spring-security#intro-to-spring-security-5-core-classes).

Comment: Thanks but I have already created the client via OAuth2 admin UI. Now, using a random value for registration id leads to an error saying client_credentials is not the right grant for that client. How do I find registration id of existing client?